# Is there a way to pam_tty_audit on Linux OpenVZ containers?

Tags: linux, openvz, audit, tty

Looks like pam_tty_audit in Linux (http://www.slashzero.com/2009/11/shell-session-logging/) could have been a great way to help figure out "what happened!" when one gets rooted.

I say "could have been" because the rootkits do clean logs and kill remote logging before they do anything else.

Say I know that some of my OpenVZ containers get rooted and I trust that my OpenVZ hardware root did not. Could I have audited from the OpenVZ hardware node on all the TTYs of the containers?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of catching audit logs with auditd, you can configure syslog on the OpenVZ VE to send all logs to a remote server (which could be the OpenVZ HN itself, for example). Thus, all audit events would be safe from a VE compromise.

I'm marking this answer as wiki in case somebody wants to provide further details.

Comment: I agree. Thank you. I now have 2 more points: (1) The HN has direct access to the TTYs; (2) It would be easier to for the adversary to kill remote logging than to avoid TTYs. I edited my question to reflect your input.

Comment: As a side note, keep in mind it is not necessary to use a TTY for hacking. A vulnerable service could be used to establish a C&C channel for the attacker without a single blip on TTYs.